# how to calculate the difference between the two fields in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

on **SQL**:

```
SELECT lastTime - firstTime as result FROM times;
```

How the query will look into the **Elasticsearch**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer:

```
{
   "size": 10,
    "script_fields": {
      "duration": {
        "script": "doc[\"lastTime\"].date.getMillis()/1000  - doc[\"firstTime\"].date.getMillis()/1000"
      }
    }
  }
```